# Color identification using image processing

Tags: image-processing, colors

I want to detect the color of an image, which contains two objects: an alphanumeric character embedded in a shape (a square, rectangle etc.). Can someone tell me how to achieve the goal?

PS - I have the code to identify colors from an image like this one:

[image: Example image]

Comment: Please add some more information, code and details that will help others understand what you've done and give them more context.

Comment: Hi Avish, it's not clear what you're asking. If you've already got the code to do the job, what assistance do you need from us?

Comment: If I'm correct, the goal is to determine the colour of the alphabet ?

Comment: yes you are right, the ultimate goal is alphabet color recognition

Comment: In that case, I suppose you need to first detect and localize the alphabet and then figure out the colour of it. You can do this by first using methods like HaarCascade to localize the alphabet. Once you have the coordinates, you can slice your array and get the region of the image where the alphabet is. From there, you can use clustering algorithms such as K-Means and get the average pixel value of the character. There are many other options to do achieve your goal of course. This is one of it.